# How to use Quick Notes with virtual desktops

Tags: spaces, notes.app, mission-control

The Quick Note feature of Notes.app is interesting, either through its shortcut fn Q or through the active corner to write down a bit of information you need.

However, I find it rather incompatible with the way I use virtual desktops (Spaces) :

I have always 5-6 active Spaces with ~10 apps open and I switch spaces with cmd tab to go to the app I want. To do that, I need to I have the preference set in Mission Control to open the space with the app windows.

Now when I do a quick Note I am switched to the Space where Notes is opened, which defeats the purpose of using Quick Note in the space I was before as a scratchpad.

Is there anyway to force Quick Note to open in the space I'm in while still using multiple spaces ?

What is your usage of Quick Note ?

I am on Monterey.

Comment: Is it opening a previous note? There's a setting for that. You can open a new note each time instead of resuming the previous one.

Comment: Thanks from bringing this setting to my attention. Helas, It happens independently from this setting.